# Is there a way of turning flow chart code into an Javascript code without using if statements or looping statements?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic, flowchart

Is there a way of turning flow chart logic into Javascript code without using if statements or looping statements?

I am curious to learn different ways of turning flow chart logic into code so that I can choose the best depending on the situation.

```
Step 1. START
Step 2. Input x
Step 3. In case A go to Step 2 if case B go to step 4 if case C go to step 5
Step 4. Output x
Step 5. Output y
Step 6. END
```

Are there better/different ways of turning the logic above into code without using if statements or looping statements?

Comment: Are you asking whether there are languages where your logic can be implemented without using IF or LOOP statements?

Comment: I am asking specifically in javascript Is it possible?

Comment: One thing that you can do is use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to map cases A, B, C to functions f, g, h, and execute the function corresponding to the current case.